# Where to put method that combines two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby and new to Rails.

I have a method that queries two different data models, combines the results and returns the combined results

```
def combine_models
    ...
end
```

The method currently resides in a controller. I want to move the method to a module or class (still unsure which) so that the method can be used in multiple controllers.

1) Where is the best place to put this?

2) Should it be a module or a class?

3) What would the contents of the .rb file look like?

Currently I have it in `/models/combine_class.rb`. The contents of the file are:

```
class CombineClass
    def combine_models
        ...
    end
end
```

The class appears to auto load, but to call the method I must use `CombineClass.new.combine_models`.

4) Is that the proper way to call the method? Is there a way I could call the method without `.new.`?

Comment: answer for 4) only if you make method as `static` or `class` method

Comment: To clarify Nermin's comment, you would change `def combine_models` to `def self.combine_models`. Also, if you aren't storing any state, I'd make it a module, leave the method as `def combine_models` and `include` it in `ApplicationController`.

Comment: @ptd Thanks for the clarification. I have changed it from class to module. I added `include CombineClass` to `ApplicationController`, but now I get error: `undefined method 'combine_models' for CombineClass:Module`. I also tried `require 'combine_class'`, but get same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to read this article: [Structuring Rails Applications](http://karolgalanciak.com/blog/2013/10/06/structuring-rails-applications/) and extract your logic into `app/usecases/model1_model2_combiner_usecase.rb`( `app/models` isn't really a good place for this), which may look like this:

```
class Model1Model2CombinerUsecase
  def self.run
    ...
  end
end
```

Of course rename it properly, then just call it in your controller with

```
@combined_models = Model1Model2CombinerUsecase.run
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I have been researching this problem for a while and wanted to use `app/projectname/file_name.rb`, but could not get it to work because I was not using `def self.run`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to put in into the concerns folder of the model dir.

models/concerns/combine_models.rb:

```
module CombineModels
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def combine_model1_model2
    ...
  end
end
```

In your models you can include the module:

```
class Model1
  include CombineModels

  ...
end

class Model2
  include CombineModels

  ...
end
```

You can use your combine methods in every model, which includes the CombineModels module

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing actually wrong with leaving your class in the models directory although the newest Rails convention is to make it a concern.

If you only want the aggregate of some property of the two models and there isn't other behavior that your combination class is going to implement I would go with a simple solution like this.

```
class CombineFooAndBar
  def self.combine_models(f, b)
    f.x + b.y
  end
end

class Foo
  attr_accessor :x
end
class Bar
  attr_accessor :y
end

f = Foo.new
f.x = 2
b = Bar.new
b.y = 3

puts "CombineFooAndBar value is #{CombineFooAndBar.combine_models(f,b)}"
```

If you need more behavior later then I would refactor it to a concern at that time.